# Grabbing post data from an array of selection boxes

Tags: php

This has been driving me crazy for the past few days. I've done something similar with check boxes and figured this would work but it didn't. I have my selection box set up like this..

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryResult2))
{

echo "<table border=\"1\" \"black\" \"solid\">";
   echo "<tr><th>News item</th><td>";
   echo $row['heading'];
  echo "</td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><th>Order</th><td>";

 if( $row['id'] == 0)
 $id = "first";
 if( $row['id'] == 1)
 $id = "second";
 if( $row['id'] == 2)
 $id = "third";
 if( $row['id'] == 3)
 $id = "fourth";
 if( $row['id'] == 4)
 $id = "fith";
 if( $row['id'] == 5)
 $id = "sixth";
 if( $row['id'] == 6)
 $id = "seventh";
 if( $row['id'] == 7)
 $id = "eighth";
 if( $row['id'] == 8)
 $id = "ninth";
 if( $row['id'] == 9)
 $id = "tenth";

 echo "<select name='order[]'>
 <option value='$id'>". $id ."</option>
 <option name='first' value='1'>first</option>
 <option name='second' value='2'>second</option>
 <option name='order[]' value='3'>third</option>
 <option name='order[]' value='4'>fourth</option>
 <option name='order[]' value='5'>fith</option>
 <option name='order[]' value='6'>sixth</option>
 <option name='order[]' value='7'>seventh</option>
 <option name='order[]' value='8'>eighth</option>
 <option name='order[]' value='9'>ninth</option>
 <option name='order[]' value='10'>tenth</option>
 </select>";
```

Then it comes over to the next page like this when I do a  print_r($_POST);

Array ( [order] => Array ( [0] => first [1] => second [2] => third [3] => fourth [4] => fith [5] => sixth [6] => seventh [7] => eighth [8] => ninth [9] => tenth ) )

How can I grab all of my data and put it into a variable so that I may update my database with this information?

Comment: You've got it all wrong. Format your code.

Comment: Just a note, consider using `switch` for readability and optimization. Switch will terminate the conditional check on the first matching condition.

Comment: @TomcatExodus: I agree or, at least, an if - else if construct. Anyway I cant' really understand what he is trying to do

Comment: @Ass3mbler - I can't figure it out either.  Does he want something preselected?  @Guyver - why are you specifying a name for each option.  Read the spec - provide the name for the select (i.e. `<select name="order">`) and not in the option tags (i.e. `<option value="1">first</option>`)

Comment: Ignore the if statement, I just included those so there wouldn't be a mystery variable there.

Comment: @Guyver: It appears that you want your select input to allow for multiple selections? Is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you will want something similar to the following:

```
<form action="some_file.php" method="post">

 <select multiple="multiple" name="test[]">
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
  <option value="5">Test 5</option>
 </select>

 <input type="submit" />

</form>
```

You do **not** want `name` attributes on the `option` items. This might be messing it up for you.

What I think you should do:

- Add `multiple="multiple"` to the `select` tag
- Remove `name` attributes from the options in the `select` input